pleiades eclipse 横に長い(一画面で収まらない)コードを書いた時のエディタのバグについて
pleiades eclipseにて
横に長い(一画面で収まらない)コードを書いた状態で、コードの最後尾あたりに文字を入力したときに、画面がコードの先頭に勝手に移動します。カーソルは移動しません。そのため、新たな文字の入力などの操作をした場合は入力している部分に画面が再度移動しますが、連続的な操作をやめると、またコードの先頭に画面が移動します。
コードが長ければ必ず発生するものでもなく、この挙動の発生条件はわかりません。
HTML,JS,XMLなど拡張子を問わず発生します。
eclipse（pleiades）のversionが違うものでも発生しており、ほんとによくわかりません。
自身の操作と画面の動きがずれるため酔いそうです。
お助けください。

前提として、保守性を考えるとあまりにも横に長いコードは避けたほうがいいと思います。
個人的にSQL文を書くときに長くなりがちなので、そういった場合は
String sql = "select * from ...." +
"where ..."
のようなかたちでクエリを複数行に分割して書いたりします。
Javaなどで関数の呼び出しが続いて長くなるような場合は、一部を変数に置き換えたりすると読みやすくなると思います。
Eclipseの使い心地については、エディタの折り返し(ワードラップ)をONにすることで改善しないでしょうか。
https://zenn.dev/ctrlkeykoyubi/articles/eclipse-install-settings#3.3.-エディタの折り返し%28ワードラップ%29をデフォルトでonにする
Eclipseのおかしな挙動については、自環境（pleiades-2022-06-java-win-64bit_20220619）をつかって400文字くらいで試しましたが残念ながら再現できませんでした。謎ですね…！
Eclipseに関する既存のバグ検索やバグの報告は以下のサイトでできるようですので、見てみると何か対策が見つかるかもしれません。
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/
とくにこの辺、似た事象に見えます。質問者様の環境でも再現している旨をコメントすることでバグ対応が再開されるかもしれません。
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461122
